# Symfony 4.2 and Nelmio Api Doc Bundle - Several documentation with multiple Controllers

Tags: api, symfony, symfony4, nelmioapidocbundle

I'm using Symfony 4 and Nelmio Api Doc Bundle to create a service that will be only accessible trough APIs (both public frontend and private back office will be created using a JS framework)

I need 2 documentations (maybe more later) :

- /api/doc
- /admin/doc

Right now I have some Controllers in src/Controllers/Admin and src/Controller/API since they are really different.

I don't understand how to use Nelmio Api Doc Bundle to handle the 2 documentations in 2 differents urls. I know there are areas but I just don't get how to deal with them...

Can someone help me by providing a simple example ?

Thanks

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html , I think you have to configure it in the yaml

Answer (score 4):

As you mention you need to configure the areas section of the nelmio_api_doc.yaml file as listed here https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/areas.html

In your case you would have the package nelmio_api_doc.yaml file as something like:

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    areas:
        default:
            path_patterns: [ ^/api ]
        admin:
            path_patterns: [ ^/admin ]
```

Or whatever the patterns in your routes are to these so it knows which controller function(s) to check for the swagger annotations.

And in your routing config nelmio_api_doc.yaml:

```
app.swagger_ui:
path: /doc/{area}
methods: GET
defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger_ui, area: api }
```

So the api documentation will be accessible via /doc or /doc/api, any other areas can be accessed by adding appending the area name for example /doc/admin etc.

Note that I have set the route as /doc/ to prevent a conflict with the firewall pattern set for ^/api picking it up first as it may conflict, you could add an extra firewall rule to catch it first, I decided to just change the route for this. 
If you went with the swagger ui route as /api/doc you would need to change the default area path patterns to:

```
path_patterns: [ ^/api(?!/doc$) ]
```

As show in the symfony docs.